# Posting pynamic card as form submission to angular component

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic, submission

This is the screen where I am displaying n number of cards based on database results and for every card join button will be there. When user clicks on join button, that particular card data should be posted to component.

I thought of using hidden fields but the values shown in the card are dynamic and every hidden field will have dynamic ID and I was unable to post those dynamic ids data.

Could someone please help me how to send that specific card data to component ts and how to read it there

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let contest of contests">
  <div class="container">
    <form (ngSubmit)="initiateJoinContest(f)" #f="ngForm">
    <h4><b>{‌{contest.data.name}}</b></h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2" >Join Fee : </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">Rs.{‌{contest.data.join_fee}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">Created on </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">{‌{contest.data.creation_date}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">Contest ends On : </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">{‌{contest.data.end_date}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">Ends In : </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">{‌{contest.data.ends_in}}</div>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: right;width:40%"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Join</button></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you submitting to? Can you share your js/ts code for that? What part of your data is dynamic?

Comment: i got the answer. instead of using form submit. i just used button submit and on click of that button sent the corresponding contest info to ts. it worked. iam able to fetch selected contest data in component

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Instead of using form submit. I just used button submit and on click of that button sent the corresponding contest info to ts. It worked. I am able to fetch selected contest data in component.